# Openlitespeed through openresty load balancer giving 404 from measure tools and from proxy

Tags: nginx, litespeed

i have an openresty load balancer between two web servers now (for testing purposes) one is nginx and the other one is openlitespeed.
the nginx one is working as it should and everything is okay.
the openlitespeed has a weird problem that i can't resolve if there is a way to solve it :
when accessing the website from a browser it's working as it should but when using measuring tools like google page insights or gtmetrix or even accessing the website from a proxy website is giving 404 response is there a way to solve this or what even is the problem.
openresty config is just like this

```
upstream backend {
        server xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx;
}

server {
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://backend;
    }
}
```

and the openlitespeed i configure it from the web interface and i don't think if it matters to post it here

and thank you

Comment: That is a weird case, you might want to turn on debug log from OpenLiteSpeed and compare the request/header between the browser and tools. Also, does curl work?

Comment: Use a tool like Wireshark to analyze the packets in/out and that should tell you why 404 errors occur.

Comment: thank you guys for your replies i solved the error by adding index.php to openlitespeed. but i still don't understand why it's working from the browser and not in the proxy sites.